# End for loop based on If statement

Tags: c, for-loop, cs50

I'm new to C and going through CS50 course currently.
I'm trying to identify if a character in a string is a digit. If there is a non-digit character, the program needs to end and send an error message.

When the program identifies a non-digit it will print out my "Not a digit" statement, but keep running the program. How can I make the program stop once that non-digit value is identified? I've also tried using break instead of returning 1.

```
int only_digits(string key)
{
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(key); i<n; i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(key[i]) == 0)
        {
            printf("Not a Digit\n");
                return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit to add my main function:

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (argv[1] < 0)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    string dig = argv[1];
    only_digits(dig);

    string plain = get_string("Enter Text: ");
    printf("Plaintext: %s\n", plain);

}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You haven't shown us the `main` program that calls your function ... but you'll need to check the value returned. If that's 1, then quit the program.

Comment: You shouldn't print `is a digit` in the loop. If the key contains several digits followed by a non-digit, you'll get a bunch of `is a digit` messages first. Print that at the end of the loop, before `return 0`.

Comment: Your return values are backwards. `1` is true, `0` is false, so it should return `1` at the end.

Comment: @Barmar Tell that to the folks who designed `strcmp`. xD

Comment: Don't hard-code ASCII values. Use the built-in `isdigit()` function.

Comment: @AdrianMole `strcmp()` is not a boolean test, it's tri-valued: Less than, equal, greater than.

Comment: You're learning so this may not be obvious: As presented, when the `if()` condition is true (ie: non-digit encountered) the function returns (after printing something). There's no need to use `else` or the level of indentation required. Consider removing the word `else` and think through the flow of the code...

Comment: `key[i] < 48 || key[i] > 57` horrible

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, this is getting much better. So I've updated the code to get rid of those ASCII values. It's now identifying a digit properly, but the program doesn't end when it's a non-digit. I've tried flipping my return values as well, but I think I'm still missing how return values work.

Comment: Finally got it to work! Yall are the best! Thank you!

Comment: @Ryan Lewis, Do not use `strelen()` here.  Consider a million long `"x..."` string.  The call to `strelen()` obliges a run through all million characters, only for the function to return of the first iteration.  Take advantage the the _null character_ is not a digit.  Better as `int only_digits(const string key) { while (isdigit(*key)) key++; return *key == 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

You revised your question based on the feedback.  This means I would have to either summarize the comments, or review each revision to figure out what changed.  To me, it only makes sense to revise the question to clarify it or add missing information.

I added the missing headers, reworked `only_digits()` to eliminate `strlen()`, and removed the 2nd test in `main()` as I was not sure what you were trying to do (it was comparing a string with 0 which was probably wrong).

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "cs50.h"

int only_digits(string key) {
    for(; *key; key++)
        if(!isdigit(*key))
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    string dig = argv[1];
    if(!only_digits(dig))
        printf("Not a digit\n");

    string plain = get_string("Enter Text: ");
    printf("Plaintext: %s\n", plain);
}
```